# Solving logarithm equation of $\log_{3}(5x-2)+\log_{3}(x)=4$

Tags: logarithms

My work so far is
$$\log_{3}(5x-2)+\log_{3}(x)=4$$
$$\log_{3}(5x-2)+\log_{3}(x)=\log_{3}(81)$$
$$\log_{3}\left(x(5x-2)\right)=\log_{3}(81)$$
$$5x^2-2x-81=0$$

Is it correct so far ?
Thanks for your help and suggestion.

Comment: ... and now the quadratic equation...

Comment: Correct, but you have to watch out for extraneous roots. Those would be cases in which $x(5x-2)$ is positive but $x$ and $5x-2$ are negative. You can't take the logarithm of a negative number. (WARNING: DO NOT learn a rule that says a logarithm cannot be negative. That is false. The thing that can't be negative is the number whose logarithm you take.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, except that you need to ensure $x>0$ and $5x-2>0$. This is implicit in the question, since the logarithm only takes (strictly) positive arguments. So solving the quadratic equation you got, you will end up with two answers, but one of them will be negative and hence needs to be rejected.

Comment: Yes, sir. I got 2 solutions. They are $\left(\sqrt(406)+1\over5\right)$ and $-\left(\sqrt(406)-1\over5\right)$ which one i should remove ?

Comment: Oh okay iknow that. The negative one. Thank you sir.

Comment: @bambangnugroho Yes, your thinking is correct. (Misread your comment just now, sorry.)

Comment: Thank you sir. I get more knowledge. I am happy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First declare that $x>2/5$, then
$$\log_{~3} (5x-2) +\log_{~3} x=4 \implies \log_{~3} [x(5x-2)]=\log_{~3} 3^4\implies 5x^2-2x-81=0 \implies x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{1624}}{10}$$ So only one root as $x=\frac{2+\sqrt{1624}}{10}\approx 4.22$ is positive and greater than $2/5$.